# Source maps not updated when changing code while debugging NestJS app in Docker container

Tags: typescript, docker, debugging, nestjs, vscode-debugger

## Problem description

I have a NestJS application that is built in Docker container. I was able to successfully setup debugging. Also, when I adjust the code while app is running, the app is recompiled and restarted and incorporated changes are reflected in behavior of the app.

However, as I do the changes in code, it seems as if source maps are not updated. So, after adding/deleting few lines of code in VS Code, I cannot correctly setup breakpoints and step into the changed code.

See the following two pictures that illustrate my problem:

### Picture 1

This shows the correct behavior in VS Code after fresh start of my app. After stepping over line 281, variable content was written to console.

[image: Note that code on line 281 correctly wrote to console variable content]

### Picture 2

On the second picture I added few lines of code. Now I clicked on line 281 with the first console.log command to add a breakpoint. However, the breakpoint was added to line 288. And after stepping over first console.log, I landed on line 294.

[image]

As you can see in the console output, changes in the code were reflected correctly. Only the behavior of breakpoints, as well as step-by-step debugging functionality is broken.
After I stop the app by CTRL+C and start it again, everything is refreshed and working. That is, until I make some other changes.

## My setup

#### npm command I use to start my app

`nest build && docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up --build`

#### docker-compose.dev.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    
    image: registry.gitlab.com/...:api-latest
    container_name: api

    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9229:9229"
    volumes:      
      - C:\projects\..path..\src:/app/src
      - .\logs:/app/logs
    environment:
       VARIOUS_VARIABLES      
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
```

#### Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

ADD nest-cli.json .
ADD tsconfig.json .
ADD tsconfig.build.json .
ADD ./.vscode/launch.json ./.vscode/
#ADD . .

EXPOSE 3000

#VSC debug
EXPOSE 9229
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:debug"]
```

#### nest-cli.json

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": ["**/*.hbs"],
    "watchAssets": true
  }
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },

  "watchOptions": {
    "watchFile": "priorityPollingInterval",
    "watchDirectory": "dynamicPriorityPolling"
  }
}
```

#### tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

#### VS Code launch.json I use for debugging

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [      
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "address": "localhost",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/app",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "restart": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
        }
```

I have looked into several topics on Stackoverflow, for example

[How to be able to set up breakpoints correctly when using VS Code to debug a TypeScript app run using ts-node in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430105/how-to-be-able-to-set-up-breakpoints-correctly-when-using-vs-code-to-debug-a-typ)

[Debug in VS Code a Node Typescript app running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935766/debug-in-vs-code-a-node-typescript-app-running-in-docker)

[Debug the nestjs project in vscode using docker does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75073538/debug-the-nestjs-project-in-vscode-using-docker-does-not-work)

[Debugging nest.js application with vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504765/debugging-nest-js-application-with-vscode)

In many posts I looked in, problem was debugging not working at all which is not my case. But I could have just overlook an existing solution. If anyone could help me with solving this, I would really appreciate it.